# Show that PTIME and PSPACE is closed under Klenee star

Tags: computational-complexity, computability

how to show that PSPACE and PTIME are closed under Kleene star ?  I can only show that NP is closed, but it is easy because we can use non-determinism to guess partition of word. In these two cases I don't have idea how to attack it.

**Edit**
Using @sdcvvc's hint.
Is obvious that when we build this graph the task is solved - it is because of the fact in linear time we check if there exists path from $1$ to $|w|$ where $w$ is input word.

So, **how to build this graph in polynomial time and space** ?
This building will be polynomial, lets consider position $i+1$, where for $1,2,3..,i$ . To build graph for $i+1$ we must (in pesimistic case) launch Turing machine for $L$ on words: $w[1,i+1], w[2,i+1],..,w[i,i+1]$. It consumes $(i+1)\cdot f(n)$ where $f(n)$ is polynomial. We can see that it is polynomial time and space.

Comment: Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has been cross-posted to [cs.se] where it has been answered: [Show that PTIME and PSPACE is closed under Klenee star](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/71895).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: Consider a graph $G$ where vertices are positions in the word, and there is an edge $i \to j$ if the subword $w[i..j-1]$ is in $L$. Show that this graph can be computed in $PTIME$ (or $PSPACE$). Can you make a connection between this graph and Kleene star $L^{\ast}$?

Comment: Did you mean dynamic algorithm ?

Comment: What do you mean by dynamic algorithm?

Comment: Ok, let me rethink your hint again

Comment: I edited my first post and tried to exploit your hint, try to check it, please

Comment: Yes, it's correct.

Comment: Simply, edges in this graph may be : $n + (n-1) + ... + 1 ~ n^2$. And $n^2\times$ runtime of MT. So polynomial. Yeah?

Comment: Yes, ${n \choose 2}$ edges, therefore $O(n^2) \times$ runtime of the Turing machine.